# How to show/hide one dynamic element (div) at a time with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

This is my first attempt at jQuery and I'm using a basic tutorial I found here: http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/#

This is my current code and how the jQuery works: http://jsfiddle.net/mZQsu/

As you can see, when you click the '+/-' it opens all 4 of the tables/DIVs.

How can I modify this code to open just the relevant secondary table/div according to the original table?

(Please note the secondary tables are generated dynamically from PHP and SQL data)

Thanks.

P.S all my code is here http://jsfiddle.net/mZQsu/ instead of clogging up this question page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/mZQsu/7/)

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {   // had to differentiate the main togglers with a new class
    var ind = $(this).parents('tr').index()-1;    // could change
    $(".slidingDiv").eq(ind).slideToggle();
});

$('.show_hide').click(function() {   // this are the 'togglers' inside the big menus
    $(this).parents(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be if you tag each of your div's with an id. E.g.

```
<div class="slidingDiv" id="ip_127_0_0_1">
```

and then modify the equivalent links to do

```
$("#ip_127_0_0_1").slideToggle();
```

so just the associated div gets expanded.

Answer (score 0):

See my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mZQsu/1/

You can use the index of the row, and toggle only the matching row of the other table using jQuery `index` and `eq`

See the relivant docs here:

- [jQuery index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [jQuery eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Be aware that if the order of the divs/rows do not match this won't work!

Comment: @k_wave the context of the question suggests that they always will be

Comment: How would I then be able to close hide the div? There always seems to be one open..

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

Since the slidingDiv class is a direct parent of the show_hide link, I could have used "parent" rather than "parents".  The latter provides more flexibility because it traverses all ancestors looking for the class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified code - http://jsfiddle.net/mZQsu/3/

I have added show-hide1, show-hide2, show-hide3, show-hide4.
And clicking on it opens respectively slidingDiv1, slidingDiv2, slidingDiv3, slidingDiv4.

Answer (score 0):

When you are binding to an event: You can always grab that event target and reference it.

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).parent("div.slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

.parent() is a good place to start, but .closest() also might work. That being said, this is the preferred way to go about it.

On a side note if you ever want to do the opposite you could use .not(e.target) and all the other elements except for the one your click will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Since your html is PHP-generated, it should not be a problem to include unique IDs for both +- links and sliding divs, for example:

```
a href="#" class="show_hide" id="show_hide2"
```

And
    div class="slidingDiv" id="slidingDiv2"

Then in your click function you get the index of the div that you want to open:

```
    $(.show_hide).click(function(){
    var $str = $(this).attr('id');
    var $index = $str.charAt( $str.length-1 );
    });
```

Now you can use index to open the div:

```
    var divName = "#slidingDiv" + $index;
    $(divName).slideToggle();
```

Comment: i'm trying your method quickly but can't get it to work. Can you check out http://jsfiddle.net/rday89/YqMZj/ and see what i'm doing wrong??