# How to show/hide dynamic elements using html ID's and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844255/how-to-show-hide-one-dynamic-element-div-at-a-time-with-jquery/8844557#8844557)  where I wanted to get a single div to show/hide rather than all the divs. This was solved and I used one of the answers provided. However further down the line I ran into some problems where it would open the wrong corresponding div and it was suggested that I use ID's to open the correct corresponding div. The divs are dynamically generated along with their ID's and they are matching as expected.

My problem is that the jQuery script doesn't work any more (i've rewritten it using advice from other answers in the previous question) - does anyone know what the problem is?

[Here is the code (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/zaCRH/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick look at the javascript console (F12) showed the following error message:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: $index is not defined
```

This error is raised because you are trying to use the variable `$index` outside of the scope it is defined (within the click handler).

Here is a working modified version with the following alterations:

- within an event handler, using `this.id` is sufficient to get the ID of an element as `this` in an event handler is a DOMElement and not a jquery object
- use .replace() or .substring() to get the last two digits of the id. .charAt() only returns 1 character at the specified position
- the ID selector in jquery is `#<id>` --> `"#slidingDiv" + idx`
- only prefix the jquery variables with `$`, not regular variables. it is just a convention but when you see `$myvariable` you then expect it to be a jquery object

---

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/fhBhR/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $(".show_hide").click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        var idx = id.replace('show_hide', '');
        //var idx = id.substring(id.length-2);
        var divName = "#slidingDiv" + idx;
        $(divName).slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and answer Didier. Works as I hoped! :)

Answer (score 1):

Three things - you've got the closing } of the inner function in the wrong place, you should be using .substring() to get the last TWO characters of the link ID, and you're using a css className selector, not an ID selector, when you look up the corresponding  element.

http://jsfiddle.net/uvLfc/

That said, a better approach would be to store the numerical portion of the ID in a data attribute on the link, or potentially even store the actual ID of the target DIV, eg.

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-targetdiv="slidingDiv99"> +/-</a>
...
<div id="slidingDiv99">...</div>


<script>
$(".show_hide").click(function(){
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-targetdiv')).slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in one of the selector and I have also modified the logic to get the index of the slidingDiv.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $(".show_hide").click(function(){
        var $str = $(this).attr("id");
        var $index = $str.replace('show_hide', '');


        var divName = "#slidingDiv" + $index;
        $(divName).slideToggle();

    });

});
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaCRH/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have a type-o in your code. Put the closing }) outside the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $(".show_hide").click(function(){
        var $str = $(this).attr("id");
        var $index = $str.charAt( $str.length-2 );

        var divName = ".slidingDiv" + $index;
        $(divName).slideToggle();

    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the method `on()` which you can then use to bind event handlers to dynamically generated objects. It's easy enough to work with. The documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).